# I get an undefined Index on my $_POST

Tags: html, forms, post, input

I am getting an undefined index error on my $_POST['msgRetrieve']. I don't why I am getting this notice, can anyone see why? The form and the $_POST and are on seperate pages

Javascript code (generate a message by choosing 3 random letters):

```
var alphabet = [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" ];  

function generateRandomString(strLength) {     
    var output = "";     
    for (var i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {         
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length);         
        output += alphabet[randomIndex];     }     
        return output; }

        function getMsg() {     
            var randomDiv = document.getElementById("messages");     
            newText = generateRandomString(3);     
            randomDiv.innerHTML = newText; 
            }  

         function validation() {
var msgRetrieveO = document.getElementById("messages");

var errIdMsgO = document.getElementById("idAlert");


    if (msgRetrieveO.innerHTML == ''){
          errIdMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select a Message";
          isDataValid = false;
    }else{
          errIdMsgO.innerHTML = ""; 
    }
    }
```

Html code:

```
 <form action="Input1" method="post" id="InputForm">
          <table>
          <tr>
          <th>Get message</th>
          <td><input id="msgBtn" type="button" value="Get Messages" name="msgid" onClick="getMsg()" /></td>   <!-- Get Messages here-->
          <td><input type="hidden" id="messages" name="msgRetrieve" /></td>
          </tr>
          </table>
</form>

<p>Get Message: {$_POST['msgRetrieve']}</p>
```

Comment: Can you post the content of `getMsg()`?

Comment: All this code is in the same form ? If so, the first time around it would be undefined because it's not a postback.

Comment: No they are on seperate pages

Answer (score 0):

Are you posting this form to the same page? u need php to echo your post btw.. and is generally on a different page which is called through ur form action (as u have action="Input1")

```
<p>Get Message: <?php echo $_POST['msgRetrieve']; ?></p>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry no the $_Post and form are on seperate pages

Comment: <form action="Input1" ... is your form pointing to that php page ? not really clear how u r submitting your form